Get extensions version number
I need to get the extensions version number for the extensions I am coding. However, I could not find a way to do so except reading the toml file as it is and then filter for the 'version' keyword and get the value this way. This does not seem correct to me. There must be a better way?
Thanks for the help in advance :)

Does this answer solve the question?
